# NoSQL good solution for daily data?

Tags: mongodb, relational, database, nosql

I'm developing a restaurant application and there will be daily orders for particular guests. because of that daily base of data I thought to use a NoSQL Database e.g. MongoDB to avoid a lot of joins in a relational database (e.g. meal of an order for a particular day of a particular guest ). Other data like guest data (pre name, last name ....) would be stored in a relational database.
What do you think? Is a NoSQL Database a good solution for that type of problem?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick with a traditional RDBMS - unless this is a project to learn/understand MongoDB/other, a normal RDBMS is going to help you achieve what you want much more easily.

Databases in the style of Mongo offer a number of advantages over traditional RDBMSs, but these advantages are only really in areas such as:

- handling/processing immense (web-scale?) quantities of not-particularly-structured data
- providing very very quick performance on cheaper hardware
- providing easy clustering for maximum uptime

The application you describe on the other hand is unlikely to need near-bulletproof uptime, and is also unlikely to need to process/store massive quantities of data quickly.

Your data sounds very structured with clearly-defined relationships, and even a very busy restaurant is not going to produce the amounts of data that would justify sharding/clustering in the MongoDB style of things.

So, unless you are looking for a project to help you learn MongoDB, I would recommend sticking with a traditional database.

Comment: I think i will go with the RDBMS approach, because of the reason you mentioned. But through my research into MongoDB it looks very good and I will use it in a test project.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than a weak description of your requirements in order to give any hint.

If your data model fits the options of MongoDB (no JOIN, embedded documents, database references) then give it a go.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

In addition google for "Mongodb Schema Design"...lots of useful slides and blogs coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both mysql and MongoDB for my app. Let's face it, as hard as I tried, I still needed some type of join queries. In Mongo, it meant making two calls to the DB but because it was so quick, I didn't take a performance hit.  I stored my user session information inside MySQL and use Mongo to store user information. What I love about it is the geo-spatial feature.